# Using an observer within an Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observer-pattern, rails-engines

I've created an Engine which is basically used for all of our projects.

Now what I want to do is add a `before_create` callback to all of the models in this Engine.

After some searching I found out that an observer is the way to go.

So, I've created this observer:

```
# app/models/baco/auth/auth_observer

class Baco::Auth::AuthObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def before_create( record )
    p record
  end

end
```

And now I need to add it to the application, but of course in my Engine there is no such file as application.rb, so I've placed it in my engine:

```
# lib/baco/auth/engine.rb

require 'rails'
require 'devise'

module Baco
  module Auth
    class Engine < Rails::Engine

      engine_name 'baco_auth'
      config.active_record.observers = :auth_observer

    end
  end
end
```

But I get the following error on starting the server:

```
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant AuthObserver (NameError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In engines, instead of `application.rb` you should use `lib/[engine_name]/engine.rb`

Also, if you create observer inside an engine, you need to namespace it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm using the engine file instead of the application.rb now. Also I placed the AuthObserver in the namespace like the rest of my engine. Only problem is, how can I point to the namespaced observer? Using :baco_auth_observer points to BacoAuthObserver instead of Baco::AuthObserver. And just :auth_observer also isn't working.

Comment: You can use `observe` method inside observer to point which model is observable

Comment: And you can point not only symbols in config. `config.active_record.observers = Baco::AuthObserver` is also acceptable

Comment: I've updated my question, pointing to Baco::Auth::AuthObserver gives a `uninitialized constant Baco::Auth::AuthObserver (NameError)` when starting the server..

Comment: Pointed to it as a string now, that seems to work.. But I think there is still something wrong with my Observer, it throws this error: `uninitialized constant Baco::Auth::Auth (NameError)`

Comment: Got it to work by changing it's name to `Baco::Auth::UserObserver`, and adding the `observe` method.. Many thanks!

Comment: How did you config it, config.active_record.observers = :user_observer ? Or you use path with module there ?